# Adding a function to one button in an array of buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to make a calculator in C# through code only (Just adding a groupBox and a label in designer). 
I have successfully added buttons a coma and a +/- sign. 
But now I am running into a problem.

I can assign a function to all of them but 
I need to assign a function separately to one of the buttons.

so far I have tried this with one button :

```
 double num = Convert.ToDouble(Answer.Text);
            Answer.Text = (-num).ToString();
```

But since I am working with arrays I have no idea how I can separate one button from another.

Essentially I should be able to do this:
If(Numbers[10].IsPressed)
 do this. 
but again I don't know the syntaxe's well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really know what you want to do... But you might try a 'big' event handler... example:

```
Button[] buttons;
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
    button.Click += MyHandler;
}

// method1
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == buttons[0])
        // Do something...
    else if(sender == buttons[1])
        // do something else...
    else if(sender == buttons[2])
        // and so on...
}

// method2
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    switch(button.Text)
    {
        case "+":
        case "1":
        case "2":
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach is having own handler for every button. Usualy Visual Studio will generate own click handler when you double click button in the designer.

```
private void ButtonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do something when "+" pressed
}   

private void ButtonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Do something when "-" pressed
}
```

You can manually add event handlers to the buttons in constructor (in case you used Visual Studio for generating it - Visual Studio will automatically add generated event handler to the button)

```
this.ButtonPlus.Click += ButtonPlus_Click;
this.ButtonMinus.Click += ButtonMinus_Click;
```

With approach above you will have own functions for every operations, which can help to maintain your code base little bid easily/faster.

However if you want to use only one event handler for all buttons, then you can use `Button.Tag` property.

Create method for every operation you have

```
private void ExecutePlus()
{
    // Do something when "+" pressed 
} 

private void ExecuteMinus()
{
    // Do something when "+" pressed 
}
```

Then in constructor save all operations in the `.Tag` property of correspondent button.

```
this.ButtonPlus.Tag = ExecutePlus;
this.ButtonMinus.Tag = ExecuteMinus;

// add "general" event handler

var buttons = new[] { this.ButtonPlus, this.ButtonMinus };
foreach(var button in buttons)
{
    button.Click += Button_Click;
}
```

Then create "general" click handler

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var button = (Button)sender;
     Action execute = (Action)button.Tag;

     execute();
}
```

You will still have separated method for every operation, but only one event handler for all buttons